# APP_INITIALIZER in library causes "Lambda not supported" error

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-packagr

When defining an `APP_INITIALIZER` in a library module, the build fails with the `Lambda not supported` error. The build error is thrown when the function is exported [as per docs](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#function-calls-are-not-supported):

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { MylibComponent } from './mylib.component';

export function myLibInit() {
  return () => console.log('Hi from exported function');
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      multi: true,
      useFactory: myLibInit
    }
  ]
})
export class MylibModule { }
```

The build error is thrown in both `dev` and `prod`.

I have alternatively also tried defining the factory function using ES6 object method shorthand notation:

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { MylibComponent } from './mylib.component';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      multi: true,
      useFactory() {
        return () => console.log('Hi from ES6 object method shorthand')
      }
    }
  ]
})
export class MylibModule { }
```

This passes both the `dev` and `prod` build, but the app throws the `ERROR TypeError: this.appInits[r] is not a function` error at runtime when the library and app is built with the `prod` flag.

How does one correctly use the `APP_INITIALIZER` in a library and not get build or runtime errors?

A reproduction can be found [here](https://github.com/samherrmann/angular-sandbox/commit/0155b17e5873f52d41c4cd6a3921035506060cc5#diff-34f36f8e2a73931ea1bfed30a4d05f22):

1. `git clone https://github.com/samherrmann/angular-sandbox.git`
2. `cd angular-sandbox`
3. `git checkout lambda-not-supported`
4. `npm install`
5. `npm run build`

GitHub issue regarding this problem can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25621).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What I understand is that while compiling, the typescript compiler tries to resolve as much as it can.

So when you are doing it like this:

```
export function myLibInit() {
  return () => console.log('Hi from exported function');
}
```

It tries to resolve it to simply `() => console.log('Hi from exported function');` because nothing else is being done in the function.

Now, let us make the function do a little more:

```
export function myLibInit() {
  var x = 2+2; //let us just do something to keep this original function
  return () => console.log('Hi from exported function');
}
```

This one compiles without error, because it is not returning the only and exactly lamda function.

Also the below one works as well because there is an extra assignment.

```
export function myLibInit() {
  var x = () => console.log('Hi from exported function');
  return x;
}
```

You can of course return a promise.

I did see your links to some tutorials and they are doing exactly what you have problem with and I think they are probably old or not done with the version of angular you are working. Because documentation clearly states that

> "The compiler does not currently support function expressions or
>   lambda functions. "

And they are doing somewhat similar to that. One reason could be that they actually never performed the build because it doesn't give you error on `ng serve`

I can see that they have closed your issue on github but I think they should review it because of my above explanation.

Comment: wow!... I confirmed that assigning the inner function to a variable before returning it does indeed work. I don't understand though why does an inline return (the way I had it) work in the app project but not in a library? How is the compilation between an app and a library different? There are even [inline returns within Angular itself](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/platform-webworker/src/web_workers/worker/location_providers.ts#L37).

Comment: I have found another open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23629) that tracks this inconsistent behavior.

Comment: The kind of inline return within angular you have pointed out is probably something you can do as well. It is within Promise. But even if it works or not, I think it is a bug and should be fixed. Or at least there should be some more explanation of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code sample above your function `myLibInit()`. See [this](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/696) for more info.

```
/**
 * @dynamic
 */
```